# Calculate the Lowest Even-Harmonic of the Values in a List

Tags: code-golf, math, number-theory

**PROBLEM**

For a list of numbers, `list`: Find the *lowest possible* integer, `x`, which is optimally close to the whole number even-harmonics of the values in list.

- `list` has a length of n, and all of the values in list are <= 2000
- `x` has a precision of 1.0 (integers only), and must be a value in the range [20, 100]
- An even-harmonic is a number that is divisible by `list` an even number of times. 20 is an even harmonic of 80 (because 80/20=**4**) -- but an odd harmonic of 60 (because 60/20=**3**).
- In this case, "optimally close" simply means to minimize the absolute cumulative remainder, relative to the nearest even harmonic of the input value(s).

  - Minimizing the absolute cumulative error takes priority over choosing the "lowest allowable value" for `x`.
  - Given `list = [151, 450, 315]` and a candidate guess of `x=25` the absolute cumulative remainder is 0.64 because 25 goes into `list` [6.04, 18, 12.6] times, respectively. The nearest even-harmonics for each instance are [6, 18, 12].

**EXAMPLE**

`list = [100, 300, 700, 1340]`

- `x = 20` is a bad solution because it is an exact or almost-exact odd-harmonic of all of the values of `list`. The number 20 goes into `list` [5, 15, 35, 67] times, respectively (odd numbers = odd harmonics = the opposite of even-harmonics).

  - The absolute cumulative remainder is 4.0 in this case (which is the maximum possible error for this instance of `list`).
- `x = 25` is a *good* solution, but not the best, because it is a exact or almost-exact even-harmonic of all of the values of list. In this case, 25 is an exact even-harmonic in all cases except for 1340. The number 25 goes into `list` [4, 12, 20, 53.6] times, respectively (even numbers).

  - The absolute cumulative remainder is 0.4 in this case.

**BONUS**

Same prompt and problem, except x has a maximum precision of 0.1 (non-integer)

Comment: Why is x=25 the best solution, and not 2? All of 100, 300, 700, and 1340 are exactly divisible by 2 an even number of times.

Comment: See bullet 2 in the problem statement.  X must be in the range [20,100]

Comment: Doesn't 20 go into 700 35 times?

Comment: For the example `[151, 450, 315]`, 75 seems to be closer than 25? `[2.01333, 6.00000, 4.2000]`? which is in absolute value `.213`, smaller than `.64`?

Comment: Good catch Giuseppe! I missed that one. Will make an edit

Comment: ...but the example you edited is the `[100, 300, 700, 1340]` one, for which it is not `.213`

Comment: Sorry about that guys. Clicking and reading too quickly for my own good. @Giuseppe the test case you're describing is not meant to imply that x=25 is the correct answer, but simply to show how to evaluate a candidate guess for `x`. I've improved the wording in that section

Answer (score 5):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.unicode`, <s>83</s> <s>78</s> 77 bytes

```factor
[ 20 100 [a,b] [ v/n [ 2 mod dup 1 > 2 0 ? - abs ] map Σ ] with infimum-by ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY5NCsIwEIX3nuIdQGvSHwQFdSdu3Iir0kXajhq0aU3SShFP4328Uh118YY373swc1SFr@1w2G93mzkq5c@BVeZE7u87@mKHC1lD11/2B63RRV0SHN1aMgX3G0ve943VxmMxGj0ghUDEmrFkFAs8v2EiEScMZILnkCIUv16qxnmGFN3U8AxR1SXKtoHEkjeBFSZQuUPG1xu8X2zumn/R5qirtprkPbIh12sEDsWVlB0@)

- `20 100 [a,b]` Create a range from 20 to 100, inclusive.
- `[ ... ] with infimum-by` Find the number in the range that is smallest when `[ ... ]` is applied to it. `with` takes our input into the `[ ... ]` in such a way that it will be underneath each number in the range on the data stack.
- `v/n` Divide each element in the input by the current number in the range.
- `[ ... ] map Σ` Map each element to a new value with the `[ ... ]` quotation and then take the sum.
- `2 mod dup 1 > 2 0 ? - abs` Find the distance to the nearest even number.

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 16 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
÷Ɱȷ2Ḃ2_«Ɗ§Ụ>Ƈ19Ḣ
```

A monadic Link that accepts a list of integers and yields an integer.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///w9kcb153YbvRwR5NR/KHVx7oOLX@4e4ndsXZDy4c7Fv3//z/a0MBAR8EYRJiDCENjE4NYAA)**

#### How?

```
÷Ɱȷ2Ḃ2_«Ɗ§Ụ>Ƈ19Ḣ - Link: list of integers, A
  ȷ2             - 10^2 = 100
 Ɱ               - map across x in [1,100] with:
÷                -   A divided by x (vectorises)
    Ḃ            - mod 2 (vectorises)
        Ɗ        - last three links as a monad - f(v=that):
     2           -   two
      _          -   subtract v (vectorises)
       «         -   minimum with v (vectorises)
         §       - sums
          Ụ      - grade-up (one-based indices sorted by the value at that index)
            Ƈ    - filter keep if:
           > 19  -   greater than 19
               Ḣ - head
```

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), 79 bytes

```javascript
a=>(m=g=o=>x++>99?o:g(a.map(v=>e+=(v/=x)&1?1-v%1:v%1,e=0)|e>m?o:(m=e,x)))(x=19)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYtBCsMgEAC/0kvLLppUSaEYWPOQ0oOkRlpiNiRFPPTv1hxmTjMfl9w@bu/12yz88mWi4shCpEBMNgthjRm4D@Da6FZIZL0gSFfKeNGDbtJZ9xXpSeHP21jbOnuZEREyaYNl5GXn2bczB5jgoZWSp@7Q/ZDubuqJWP4)

Comment: Nicely done Arnauld!

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <sup><s>75</s></sup> 73 bytes

```python
lambda l:min(range(20,101),key=lambda x:sum(min(a/x%2,-a/x%2)for a in l))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NU7NzoIwELzzFHsx7SY1tkBjQlJfBDn0w0WJUAmtCUp4drTEbw@zPzO7s8Mr3B4uWxtzXjvb/10sdEXfOj5adyWeSqGkQnGnl/nRU@GfPY8Se5h2qdhvCZvHCBZaBx3iGsgHDwZ4qaQUkEU4RlBZLisBpdJKQK4jp3SFCU0D1YEucSfVX7HGpL5Rfacxjtj5mR7zmgnYKpUxTKJhEBQt3@3AN0sB/4ewSOAb8YmGB9yaYWxd4A2bwwL7E8x@gflnUpIxvloYrh8)

*Saved 2 bytes thanks to [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/steffan)!!!*

Inputs a list of integers.
Returns the lowest even harmonic.

Comment: Nice! FYI this breaks if you feed it only a single `list`. Accepting multiple `list` inputs is not a requirement so you may be able to reduce this further by eliminating that functionality

Comment: @AustinPrater Are you confusing my test harness (which works on multiple lists) with my solution (which inputs a single list)? The test harness doesn't break on a single list. It uses tuples so you need to put a comma after a single element (eg tuple of \$1\$: `(1,)`).

Comment: I see -- makes sense

Comment: [73](https://tio.run/##NU7NzoIwELzzFHsx7SY1tkBjQlJfBDn0w0WJUAmtCUp4drTEbw@zPzO7s8Mr3B4uWxtzXjvb/10sdEXfOj5adyWeSqGkQnGnl/nRU@GfPY8Se5h2qdhvCZvHCBZaBx3iGsgHDwZ4qaQUkEU4RlBZLisBpdJKQK4jp3SFCU0D1YEucSfVX7HGpL5Rfacxjtj5mR7zmgnYKpUxTKJhEBQt3@3AN0sB/4ewSOAb8YmGB9yaYWxd4A2bwwL7E8x@gflnUpIxvloYrh8 "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 4):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 19 bytes

```
20₁ṡµ⁰$/:1%$∷1=+∑;h
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCIyMOKCgeG5ocK14oGwJC86MSUk4oi3MT0r4oiRO2giLCIiLCJbMTAwLCAzMDAsIDcwMCwgMTM0MF0iXQ==)

*-2 bytes thanks to emanresu A, and another -3 by porting 05AB1E*

Comment: I have no idea how this works but [here's 22](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLigoHJvnYv4oipMiXGmzLOtcOe4oi1O+G5oOKHp+KAuicxOT47aCIsIiIsIlsxMDAsIDMwMCwgNzAwLCAxMzQwXSJd)

Answer (score 4):

## [Burlesque](https://github.com/FMNSSun/Burlesque), 49 bytes

```
bc20 100r@)td{?/{JR_2./2.*.-ab}ms}Z]ziq[~<m-]20.+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyotykktLixN/V@U@D8p2chAwdDAoMhBsySl2l6/2iso3khP30hPS083Mak2t7g2KrYqszC6ziZXN9bIQE/7//9oQ1NDHQUTUwMdBWND01gA)

```
bc       # Repeat input list        
20 100r@ # Range [20..100]
)td      # As doubles
{
 ?/      # Divide each
 {       # -- Find difference with nearest 2
  J      # Duplicate
  R_     # Round
  2./2.* # Closest multiple of 2
  .-     # Difference
  ab     # Abs
 }
 ms      # Map sum
}Z]      # Zip range with input and evaluate
zi       # Zip indices
q[~<m-]  # Index of minimum
20.+     # +20
```

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), 72 bytes

```
\(l,m=20:200,x=outer(l,m,`/`)%%2/2)m[order(colSums(abs(x-round(x))))[1]]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMHOnPzy1OKS-My8kvjUstS8-IzEotz8vMxk26WlJWm6Fjc9YjRydHJtjQysjAwMdCps80tLUotAQjoJ-gmaqqpG-kaaudH5RSlA0eT8nODS3GKNxKRijQrdovzSvBSNCk0giDaMjYWal4bLQo1kDUNTQx0FE1MDHQVjQ1NNTQVlBXNTLnzqDUBKQYQ5iDA0NjEA6zIy5YLYtmABhAYA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 25 bytes

```
≔Ｅ⁸¹Σ↔⊖﹪⊕∕θ⁺²⁰ι²ηＩ⁺²⁰⌕η⌊η
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Rc47C8IwFAXg3V@R8QYimGpB6FRaBIdCwbF0iE0wF/LQPPr3Y3XQ6cDhg3MWLcLihSmljREfDgbxhDNn5JYttPfoTU4KerUEZZVLSsLgZTYeru5f9biiVPBiZDQ5QnVgBCmljFT0G5o2uzGgS9CJmOCHLugkaEYGdGi3Pf3htCllmni9fTjVGzryep7LfjVv) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
  ⁸¹                        Literal integer `80`
 Ｅ                          Map over implicit range
          θ                 Input array
         ∕                  Vectorised divide
              ι             Current value
           ⁺                Plus
            ²⁰              Literal integer `20`
        ⊕                   Vectorised increment
       ﹪                    Vectorised modulo
               ²            Literal integer `2`
      ⊖                     Vectorised decrement
     ↔                      Vectorised absolute
    Σ                       Take the sum
≔               η           Store in variable
                        η   List of absolute cumulative errors
                       ⌊    Find the minimum
                     ⌕      Find index in
                      η     List of absolute cumulative errors
                  ⁺         Plus
                   ²⁰       Literal integer 20
                 Ｉ          Cast to string
                            Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 3):

## APL+WIN, 43 bytes

Prompts for vector of numbers in list

```
(m=⌊/m←+/¨|¨m-⌊¨m+1≤¨2|¨m←(⊂⎕)÷¨n)/n←19+⍳81
```

[Try it online! Thanks to Dyalog Classic](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob6qvz6O2CcZcQJanP5BlyPWooz3tv0au7aOeLv1coIi2/qEVNYdW5OoCBYCUtuGjziWHVhiBhICyGo@6moB6NQ9vP7QiT1M/D2SEpfaj3s0Whv@BJnH9T@MyNDVUMDE1UDA2NOUC8gyALCA2B2JDYxMDLgA)

Answer (score 2):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 80 bytes

```cs
a=>Enumerable.Range(20,81).OrderBy(x=>a.Sum(k=>Math.Min(2-k/x%2,k/x%2))).First()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY27CsIwAEV3vyKLkECMSR8o2GQQLDgURUdxiG2qoTZC2mBF/PbY6uDkcu5wX3kzyRvtU2fyZL0yrlZWnq4qKW6uF4GBNq0AJeBecvHzyU6as4IBxXOGyMYWyi4fsONCkr2rYcVFJtsLybSBwaSaduMAf4gQIqm2TQuRX4y2tl@HJTTqDr6Hh@OTUYpBOGA2gIURfSH0LxwzDKJ4aLB4iPk3)

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 15 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
20тŸΣ/D1%sÉ+O}н
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fyOBi09Ed5xbruxiqFh/u1PavvbD3//9oQ1NDHQUTUwMdBWND01gA) or [verify both test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeWhlf@NDC42Hd1xbvGhdcX6LoaqxYc7tf1rL@z9r/M/OtrQ1FBHwcTUQEfB2NA0Vkch2tAAxAYR5iDC0NjEIDYWAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
20тŸ         # Push a list in the range [20,100]
    Σ        # Sort it by:
     /       #  Divide the (implicit) input-list by this value
      D      #  Duplicate the decimal values
       1%    #  Modulo-1 to only keep the decimal portion
      s      #  Swap so the entire values are at the top again
       É     #  Check which ones are odd (ignoring the decimal portions)
         +   #  Add the values at the same positions together
          O  #  Sum this list together
    }н       # After the sort-by, keep just the first element
             # (so `Σ...}н` basically acted as a minimum-by builtin)
             # (which is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 2):

## C, 122 bytes

```c
i,j,k;f(n,m)int*n;{float a=m,b,c;for(i=19;99/i++;k=b<a?a=b,i:k)for(j=b=0;j<m;b+=fabs(c-rint(c))*2)c=n[j++]/2./i;return k;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZBdb8IgFIavy684cXGBFrX1I4ujuB/ivKC0KG2hC61bMuNfXwfuI/HiBPKclwcOcnaUchw1rWnDFLbUEG2H2LKLajsxgOCGFlQy1TmsebZl2@1CJwlreJGLF8ELqp8bEro1L3jK6tywIuFKFD2WM@ddWBISL4nkdl8nyWGxnC80c9VwdhYadh0ftJXtuawg74dSd/PTDt2hVheBIa9CRmiL3ztdEnRBkSdgKMQWOKQUHEMo@jjptgLcS2EVnkzLCYVHQ2AHKQF/JApZV4m27aQfFgzE0OvPqlNeQ4Ig8rMADmodtMwvORgGSaJ/DNGd2@71wZ/z@C0Me@PgG//8GpzOq9Ttvhv7i852MC1frY@7wENUuarCPy/5/aOUoeu4gmyTwXqTwirboDVkqd/5evKVrdbpl1StOPbjrDXf)

#### Bonus:

## C, 134 bytes

```c
i,j,k;float f(n,m)int*n;{float a=m,b,c;for(i=199;999/i++;k=b<a?a=b,i:k)for(j=b=0;j<m;b+=fabs(c-rint(c))*2)c=n[j++]/.2/i;return k/10.;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZDbTsMwDIav26ewJg0lPaztDkIly3iQwUWaNSNtk6J0gMS0V6c4LSBxYTn67f@zHZmepRxHnTRJy1TXiwsoYhNDtb1Ell1nSXCTVIlkqndE86IsWVmWmY5j1vJqLx4FrxL90FJfb3jFc9bsDatirkQ1EJk6pBFJabSmkttjE8fP2Wqdaebqy5uz0GZFvmK3EdtCI7Ql770@0fAaBqiASSCywCFnYTDv41gYBh8vuquBDFJYRRbL0yKBO0PhADkFdAbe4mrRdb3Ei8BABIP@rHuFNOoBAa4LxE/QEx3THgyDONYzIfjHtkf9jD6UX/09kw5Y@NNvnukQpaZ5k/bbmh5guSrUk0WD8xXfrFxdk3mXn4/AE2/jBopdAdtdDptiF26hyPGFcY9RbLb5l1SdOA9j2plv)